# Proof by mathematical induction

Tags: induction, mathematical-foundations

Before we start, my textbook declares lgn as base two.

I only have one question, how did log2 become n (both highlighted in yellow in the picture)? Is it because log2 = 1, which is too small to even matter?

[image]

Comment: 1) In which way is this a computer science as opposed to a pure mathematics question? Seems to  me that this is about middle-grade arithmetics, which is probably a better fit for [math.SE]. 2) Please get rid of the image and use Markdown and MathJax to reproduce its content. 3) You need to give attribution. Which book by whom are you referencing?

Comment: "how did log2 become n" -- it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're using base-$2$ logs, $\log2=1$, so $$n(\log n-\log 2) = n\big((\log n)-1\big)=n\log n -n\,.$$

All of the stages of the calculation are written as equalities, so nothing should be being discarded as too small to matter (and nothing is).